# Flask SMS with twilio error

Tags: python, flask, sms, twilio

```
from flask import *
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

from flask import render_template
import os

#Pull in configuration from system environment variables
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = os.environ.get('Axxxxxx')
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = os.environ.get('Sxxxxxxxxx')
TWILIO_NUMBER = os.environ.get('xxxxxxx')

# create an authenticated client that can make requests to Twilio for your
# account.

#client = TwilioRestClient(account='Axxxxx', token'sxxxxxxxx')

#create a flask web app
app = Flask(__name__)

client = TwilioRestClient(account='Axxxxx', token='Sxxxxx')

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    return render_template('index.html')

#Handling a post request to send text messages.

@app.route('/message', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def message():
     # Send a text message to the number provided
    if request.method == 'POST':

        message = client.sms.messages.create(to=request.form['Phone_number'],
                                         from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                         body=request.form['body'])

    return render_template('message.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Note that in production, you would want to disable debugging
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am using flask. When i input the number and the text message it gives me this error

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Comment: Can you post the template showing your form?

Comment: It looks like you're having an error with the HTTP Method that is being used to submit the form, can you post the html template you're using for this?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Send an SMS</title></head>
<body>
<form action="/" method="POST">
Cell phone number: <input name="phone_number" type="text" />
Text in here: <input name="body" type="text" />
<button type="submit">Send Text</button>
</form>
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: @stuwie Please edit your post code in your question instead of a comment so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

You're posting to the wrong endpoint. Your form should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Send an SMS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/message" method="POST">
            Cell phone number: <input name="phone_number" type="text" />
            Text in here: <input name="body" type="text" />
            <button type="submit">Send Text</button>
        </form>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(Above, `action` was changed from `/` to `/message`.)

---

Note: if this is a template run through `flask.render_template`, you should change

```
<form action="/message" method="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="{{ url_for('message') }}" method="POST">
```

This is a more sustainable way to use urls in flask, and it will reduce your overhead if you ever need to change the value.